# Vertically centering div in table cell with divs below it

Tags: html, css

I have a table with one column having image and other columns having text. For one of the columns I wish to show additional information below main text but I wish for the main text to remain vertically centered.

This is the code I currently have:

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
}

.thumbnail {
  height: 150px;
}

.bigtext {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.smalltext {
  font-size: 0.65em;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/180x320" class="thumbnail"/></td>
    <td>
      <div class="bigtext">Should be vertically centered</div>
      <div class="smalltext">Should be below big text</div>
      <div class="smalltext">Should be below big text</div>
      <div class="smalltext">Should be below big text</div>
    </td>
    <td>Third cell</td>
    <td>Forth cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rxhz1v2f/18/

**Goal:** [image: To-be]

I know it can be done with margins etc set in pixels but I would like it to be dynamic, meaning even working if there are, for example, two rows of text with class `bigtext`.

**Edit:**
I would like the solution to be HTML&CSS only. I can change the HTML structure within table cell, if necessary.

Comment: Can you add a image or sketch on how you wish to see the final view

Comment: Sketch is included in the question - check the end of the post.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with `JavaScript` by finding the size of the sibling elements like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".bigtext:first-child").forEach(element=>{
  // Find the size of all the non-big siblings
  let siblingSize = 0
  let nextSibling = element.nextElementSibling
  while (nextSibling) {
    if (!nextSibling.classList.contains("bigtext")) {
      siblingSize += nextSibling.getBoundingClientRect().height
    }
    nextSibling = nextSibling.nextElementSibling
  }
  // Add a margin to the first .bigtext
  element.style.marginTop = siblingSize + "px"
})
```

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
}

.thumbnail {
  height: 150px;
}

.bigtext {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.smalltext {
  font-size: 0.65em;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/180x320" class="thumbnail"/></td>
    <td>
      <div class="bigtext">Should be vertically centered</div>
      <div class="smalltext">Should be below big text</div>
      <div class="smalltext">Should be below big text</div>
      <div class="smalltext">Should be below big text</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="bigtext">Should be vertically centered</div>
      <div class="bigtext">Should be vertically centered</div>
      <div class="smalltext">Should be below big text</div>
      <div class="smalltext">Should be below big text</div>
    </td>
    <td>Third cell</td>
    <td>Forth cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Getting `height` of the small texts by `sText.clientHeight` multiplying that with `3` `number of small texts` and adding that `px` value to padding top of `BtextContainer`

```js
let sText = document.querySelector(".smalltext");
    let BtextContainer = document.querySelector(".bTextContainer");
    BtextContainer.style.paddingTop=sText.clientHeight*3+"px";
```

```css
.table {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .thumbnail {
        height: 150px;
    }

    .bigtext {
        font-size: 2em;
    }

    .smalltext {
        font-size: 0.65em;
    }

    table,
    th,
    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/180x320" class="thumbnail" /></td>
            <td class="bTextContainer">
                <div class="bigtext">Should be vertically centered</div>
                <div class="smalltext">Should be below big text</div>
                <div class="smalltext">Should be below big text</div>
                <div class="smalltext">Should be below big text</div>
            </td>
            <td>Third cell</td>
            <td>Forth cell</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```